# How do you put multiple fluidRows() in one Shiny output?

Tags: r, shiny

When I try to put two fluidRows() in one output$variable, I only get the last one:

```
> {fluidRow(class="a"); fluidRow(class="b")}
<div class="row b"></div>
```

Is there a way to put two rows in one output$variable?

Comment: `tagList(fluidRow(class="a"), fluidRow(class="b"))`

Comment: That's better than the answer I came up with. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you expect, but I think thet simplest way to have multiple elements to return is using a `div`. Something like:

```
output$variable <- renderUI({
  div(
    fluidRow( class = "a"),
    fluidRow( class = "b")
   )
})
```

It will create something like:

```
<div>
  <div class="row a"></div>
  <div class="row b"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Way better than my own solution. And easier to remember.